# How to display optional fields in response when using C# WebClient and getting exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using WebClient to do a POST to a server like so:

```
string URI = "http://mydomain.com/foo";
string myParameters =
   "&token=1234" +
   "&text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(someVariable);

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
      wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }
}
```

I sometimes can get exceptions thrown due to HTTP 403 (forbidden). In those cases, I want to know the exact reason.  Digging into the service I'm calling into, it is documneted that it will **optionally** return an `errorDetail` field like so:

```
"code": 403,
"errorType": "not_authorized",
"errorDetail": "Can reply on a checkin at most once."
```

However, when I'm stepping through the code in Visual Studio, I don't see how I can get the `errorDetail` field. It doesn't apepar to be part of the `WebException`.

Is there a way to get it so I could display is something like:

```
return e.Message + " -- " + e.errorDetail
```

?

Comment: It's not at `e.Data["errorDetail"]` ?  Failing that, it should be in the `e.Response` somewhere, if it was sent at all.

Answer (score 0):

`errorDetail` is not part of the HTTP specification so `WebClient` does not know about it. For the same reason you will not find it anywhere in the BCL.

What you probably want is the response body so you can parse it (maybe as JSON? Your data looks like it).

You can get the response object from `WebException.Response`. Read it just like you normally would read a response.

Be aware that this property might be null if there is no response (due to network error, for example).